# How can I introduce a new theory and avoid self promotion making a presentation at a national conference

Tags: conference, self-promotion

Recently, I was accepted to make a 30 min oral presentation during National Conference, and are a little concerned how to avoid self promotion in my attempts to explain or announce a new theory of cognition to serve the mental health field with new therapies.

Point being, we find everywhere people and professionals talking about needing new approaches and repeating the problems with mental health, this research is offering solutions.

Is the National Stage the place to announce this, or will it be viewed as self promotion?

Comment: What kind of people are attending the conference? Have you submitted an abstract for the talk? Why do you view self promotion as negative?

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that you are talking about a hypothesis and not a theory in the scientific sense?

Comment: Please do figure out how to not give the signals of crackpottery, if you want people to take you seriously. The implicit premises of your question already verge on an attitude that would be perceived by many more-senior people as necessarily unreliable. Report the science, not your ego.

Comment: @Nathanael Farley, It is a mental health conference so there will be all sorts of professionals there, and I did submit an abstract, and I have always heard self promotion is never viewed as a good thing.

Comment: @Gerhard, I would have to say that it is a theory although tested informally it can be reproduced.

Comment: @Rcarnt: that still makes it a hypothesis (at best).

Comment: @paul garrett, thank you, I have tried a few times to answer your question without sounding egocentric.  I assume you are of the "more senior" people you mentioned, and if there is a chance you can contact me, I feel your advice would be immensely helpful.

Comment: @Rcant, if you'd like, send me email to the address on my user page here. Mostly I would reiterate comments of others. The tl;dr is "make it be about the science, not about you". And, if it's an idea without much follow-up, then it is probably premature to present it publicly. People like evidence, especially if an idea is against the grain. E.g., don't claim "here's a wonderful idea I had", but, rather, something like (this might work in math) "Consider the following hypothesis. Here are several examples that illustrate the plausibility of..."

Comment: @paul, Thank you for this but I am not familiar with this site and do not fully understand how to send you a private message, I visited your profile.  Is there even a private message option here?

Comment: @Rcant, my "profile" links to my web site, and there you can see my university email...

Comment: @paul, Okay I have sent you an email, thank you again Paul.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments - a key golden rule here is to make the focus on the science and not on yourself.

Practically speaking, the 30 minute oral presentation time slot provides an opportunity - be absolutely sure of your theory and the evidence that supports it. The organisers of the conference evidently deem that there is some potential in your research based on your accepted abstract (congratulations on that recognition!).

You are going to need:

- a very clear hypothesis about the problem you are addressing and how your proposed solution addresses it.  Be concise and to the point on this.
- Be very clear and concise about what methodology you use(d).
- But the **main part** of your talk would be to provide **reproducible and relevant evidence** to show how your proposed theory provides new therapies, and more importantly, how these new therapies are an improvement on current therapies and how this research advances the field.

A couple of pieces of advice given when I was about to embark on my first talk at a conference:

- Write in 3rd person - avoid 'I' statements (and similar).
- Stick to the point, use the time available to deliver your evidence.
- Try not to make it personal - keep it objective and based on evidence.
- Expect some hard questions to be asked of you.

As you are providing a new theory, it is absolutely of the utmost importance on you to provide the evidence to support your new theory. Don't expect your theory to be accepted straight away, or even in the short term - other researchers will need to digest and evaluate the evidence.

Essentially, you'll be not so much 'announcing' a new theory, but presenting a new theory for scientific scrutiny.

30 minutes is quite a short amount of time to state your case, so use the time wisely.